# TestCafe Visibility check techniques

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Is there any functional difference between:

```
await t.expect(Selector('button').visible).ok();
```

and

```
await Selector('button', {visibilityCheck: true})
```

?

As I understand, it does the same thing? If the selector is not visible the test will fail in both cases?

If it is different, can you give me the exact example showing the situation when it is different?

Best Regards,
Anna

Answer (score 2):

In the second case, the test will not fail, perhaps you mean

```
await t.expect(Selector(‘button’, {visibilityCheck: true}).exists).ok();
```

The best way to check whether an element is visible is to use its visible property as you do in your first code example.

The visibilityCheck option works in a different way: if it's enabled, TestCafe requires an element in an assertion to be visible. Otherwise, the test fails. For example, the following assertion fails:

```
await t.expect(Selector(‘button’, { visibilityCheck: true }).value).eql('value');


// Error: Cannot obtain information about the node because the specified selector does not match any node in the DOM tree.
```

In this case, TestCafe tries to find a visible element by using the selector, but can't find it (since the element is invisible).